# Can I leave the grill outside over winter (snow and cold in western Europe)?

Tags: outdoor, snow

Can i leave the grill outside over winter (snow and cold in western Europe)? I have a cover for the grill.

I don't have much space in the cellar and the grill is quite heavy.

this is my grill (a hype product):

[image]

Can I leave the grill outside over winter (at us there is snow and cold in Western Europe)? What exactly do I have to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't even dream of it.
I'm in London, UK. Known for rain but not particularly harsh winters.
My neighbours left their simple hibachi out over two winters, covered. I note they've now given up on it & thrown it out.

Theirs was probably worth about $£€ 80 and was purely & simply mechanical, though similar-looking to yours [initially]. Last I saw it, it was a crumbling pile of rust.

Yours, according to https://www.lotusgrill.co.uk/grills/LGR-G-XXL costs about $£€ 450 & has ***electricals*** in it [2 battery-operated fans.]
They don't say what it's made of, so assume it's not stainless steel or they'd be bragging about it.

I wouldn't even leave that out in the rain or overnight [dew-point & electricity don't mix well], let alone over winter.

Comment: Barbecue covers (and garden furniture covers) very often seem to be junk, sold as waterproof but even if they are, they soon start to leak and just keep the stuff they're covering wetter.

Comment: A cover might keep the rain off a bit; it certainly won't prevent condensation forming inside.

Comment: That too. But since I covered mine with the bag used to deliver a tonne of sand, it hasn't got any worse, so I reckon leaks are more important

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

I leave my grill outside year 'round, with a cover on it.  This is in the US, Mid-Atlantic area, and have had the grill for around 7 years now.  It's still looking good, though it is made mostly of stainless steel.  Have only had to replace the grates once.

Note, I don't think the cold/snow does much to a grill.  High humidity and frequent foggy conditions are probably a bigger issue, even with a cover.

Comment: The cover is the key.  If uncovered, I would not leave it out, as it doesn't appear that these Lotusgrills have lids.

Comment: Also make sure water can't pool on the cover - it should form a tent so the rain and melted snow can run off